# Como puedo guardar el valor de un input de tipo radio en una variable php para ingresarla en una base de datos mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Este es el Código de mi formulario php, como le hago para guardar el valor del input radio dependiendo de lo que se haya seleccionado en una variable de php, para despues insertarlo en una base de datos, de antemano Gracias!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <form action="registrar_form.php" method="post">
        <label for="">Nombre</label> <br>
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Ingrese su nombre"> <br><br>

        <label for="">Turno</label> <br>
        <input type="radio">
        <label for="">A</label> <br>
        <input type="radio">
        <label for="">B</label> <br>
        <input type="radio">
        <label for="">C</label> <br>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes poner el mismo atributo **name** a todos los inputs de radio que estén relacionados, y también un **value** diferenciado en cada uno de ellos, por ejemplo:

```
<label for="">Turno</label> <br>
<input name="turno" type="radio" value="A">
<label for="">A</label> <br>
<input name="turno" type="radio" value="B">
<label for="">B</label> <br>
<input name="turno" type="radio" value="C">
<label for="">C</label> <br>
```

y luego, en PHP, lo puedes recoger mediante la lectura de su POST así:

```
$turno = $_POST['turno'] ?? 'Ninguno seleccionado!';
```

donde, si no hay ningún botón seleccionado el valor de la variable `$turno` pasará a ser "Ninguno seleccionado!" (es un ejemplo, pon lo que quieras).

Comment: Muchas gracias!!, era justo lo que necesitaba